# How to get maven to show all compilation errors

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I am using maven and would like to have it show all errors on compilation and currently our build only shows one at a time.  I do see the option for setting the `failOnError` which you could set false but this could mean the build succeeds even though there are compilation errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you try -fae (fail at end)  together with -e -X

Comment: Thanks for he help.  I thought there would be an option in the goal but could not find it.